# Using a regex from a variable in awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a file with records separated by empty lines, something like this:

```
ID0
field1
field2
field3

ID1
field1
field2
field3

ID2
field1
field2
field3

...
```

So, to get all content of a record based on its ID I use `awk 'BEGIN {RS=""} /ID1/' file`

But, the issue is that I would like to make it with a script, with the id passed as a variable.

I have written the script like that (but it doesn't work):

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# Set Record Separator
BEGIN {RS=""}

# Search that record that contains the id
/id/
```

I call it with `./script.awk -v id=ID1 file`

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not caused by being in a script (as the original question title asserted): You would see the same problem if you were running `awk -v id=ID1 'BEGIN {RS=""} /id/' file`. The way you're using `/id/` isn't looking at the variable named `id`; instead, it's expecting `id` to be the exact regex to match.

Instead of using `/varname/` (which is treating `varname` as a regex itself instead of the name of a variable containing a regex), use `$0 ~ varname`:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

# Set Record Separator
BEGIN {RS=""}

# Search that record that contains the id
$0 ~ id
```

See this demonstrated in the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/amz1u1